# Can a linux distro be installed on a wireless dongle?

Tags: linux, wifi, system-installation, live-usb

I wonder if a Linux distribution can be installed on a WiFi dongle (or at least run from it)? Last week we had in high school a workshop which was organized by a college and they introduced us to the WPS vulnerability, with Kali Linux. I know that we have only WindowsOS and Xubuntu on the HDDs, so Kali was run from the WiFi dongles. I know how to create a Live USB drive, but I don't have the knowledge to do this on a wifi dongle, for example to run ArchLinux / Manjaro off of it.

Comment: If you can find a wireless dongle that also has storage, then why not. I don't think it's very common with wifi adapters, though, more so with mobile network adapters (3G/4G/what have you). This probably isn't OS related though

Comment: http://www.dx.com/p/igrs-linksee-usb-2-0-802-11g-wifi-wireless-remote-mass-storage-dongle-36387 - something like this (Only shown as an example, I don not advertise this)? (from the post: https://superuser.com/questions/181855/usb-wifi-dongle-device-that-can-emulate-a-virtual-mass-storage-device-for-a-home)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define WIFI dongle ? Of course you can have a WIFI chip/antenna with storage (or microsd port, like I have) on a USB dongle and can put Linux on there, I have one, it even has 3G ! You can boot the computer from it, I think, never tried, and once connected, you can even access internet via WIFI or if you have a SIM card in there, 3G.

Examples ? Google for this: "3G dongle microsd"